# Alamofire Network error exceptions handling

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am currently developing an application for iOS. Most of the features that I wanted implemented I have already finished, but there is one feature in particular that I really need to have - Network Errors handling.

So for example: A user is trying to refresh his data inside my application. Instead of my app crashing or simply not doing anything, I would love for that exception to be caught, identified and then display a corresponding message on screen using AlertDialogs. for example:

- Network Error - title;
- Unreachable host, please check your network connectivity and try again - Message;
- OK - button;

I was able to have this working in my Android application and it's quite useful, however, I am quite new to Swift and iOS development, so, please help me out here and point me in the right direction.

I am currently using latest Alamofire for sending HTTP Requests, here is my example of HTTP Request that I have implemented inside my application.

```
func loadProfile() {
   let url = Constants.profileURL
   let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Cookie": "username; password"]
   AF.request(url, method: .post, headers: headers).response {response in
      if let data = response.data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
         if  dataString.contains(Constants.loginSuccess) {
             //Do something
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So, you're looking to catch the network errors or a way to show an alert in ios similar to android?

Comment: @Frankenstein I am looking to catch network errors, I know how to show alert dialogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire's `DataResponse` (and all response types) contain the `Result` of serialization. You can use that value to check whether serialization, and the request in general, succeeded or failed. You can then pass the `result` value to completion handlers to be dealt with as you wish.